# 'Resource Acquisition Is Initialization' for solving memory leak issue

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, resources, acquisition

I am trying to optimize part of code for a project. There are some context to show:

```
Class Basic
{
  type* _shareResource;
  virtual Basic(){};
  virtual ~Basic(){};
  virtual void initialResource() = 0;
  virtual void deleteResource() = 0;
  virtual void ownmethod() = 0;
  static Basic* createChild(int condition);
}
Basic* Basic::createChild(int condtion)
{
   Basic* pointer;
   if (condition ==  1)
       pointer = new ChildA();
   else 
       pointer = new ChildB();  
   return pointer; 
}


Class ChildA::public Basic
{
  void initialResource(){ allocate memory for _shareResource;}
  void deleteResource(){ delete _shareResource; _shareResource = NULL;}
  ChildA(){ initialResource(); }
  ~ChildA(){ deleteResource(); }
  virtual ownmethod() {// child A method}

}

Class ChildB::public ChildA
{
  void initialResource(){ allocate memory for _shareResource;}
  void deleteResource(){ delete _shareResource; _shareResource = NULL;}
  ChildB(){ initialResource(); }
  ~ChildB(){ deleteResource(); }
  virtual ownmethod(){// child B method}
}
```

so, when I use Basic::createChild() as a client:
   Basic* aPointer = CreateChild(1);
   //after some usage, the client should delete this ponter
   delete aPointer;

However RALL require Basic delete itself without help from client. So I am trying to modify the code. What I did is:

```
boost::share_ptr<Basic> Basic::createChild(int condtion)
{
   boost::share_ptr<Basic> pointer;
   if (condition ==  1)
       pointer = boost::share_ptr<ChildA>(new ChildA());
   else 
       pointer = boost::share_ptr<ChildA>(new ChildB());
   return pointer   
}
```

But I got core dump as memory leak, I checked it from deleteResource() of child class, but I don't know why.

Could you help me to explain the core dump or provide a better solution for following RALL principle? Thanks a lot. (I prefer to keep createChild as static method, since my optimization should not modify too much client code)

Comment: You should delete the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator of `Basic` (or declare them private, if you're stuck in the pre-2011 world of pain), to make sure nothing is accidentally copying these objects. Otherwise, it's possible that two objects might think they own the same resource, and both try to delete it. Better still, why not make `_shareResource` itself a smart pointer?

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated !?

```
class Shared
{
   protected:
   struct Implementation
   {
       virtual ~Implementation() {}
   };

   protected:
   Shared(Implementation* p)
   : m_self(p)
   {}

   private:
   std/boost::shared_ptr<Implementation> m_self;
}
```

And have derived classes with a nested class derived from Shared::Implementation

However, passing a std/boost::shared_ptr< SomeClass > would do it, too

Answer (score 0):

Declare the destructor of Basic virtual.  It's likely the derived classes destructors are not being called.

Comment: That's good advice, but not strictly necessary when using shared pointers. They have a deleter which knows the correct type and will do the right thing.

Comment: Ah, it just looked to me like deleteResource() could potentially not be called.  Maybe shared_ptr has some functionality I'm not aware of to compensate for this.

Comment: Aha, I think I did a mistake, the destructor and constructor of basic are virtual